# cxf REST application, send request to other service

Tags: java, cxf, resttemplate, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm creating cxf REST webservice.

This service will be run under FUSE ESB.

The main thing that this webservice will do is to receive request from one service and send it to another service as a normal POST variables through HTTP.

I was trying to do this connecting cxf with camel, but i have huge problem with create this kind of project, to i would like to do this other way.

I've started to try use RESTTemplates, but after adding spring jars to my pom, my cxf webservice is not handling by FUSE ESB.

Do you know other way to do this type of application?

Additionally i add, that till now i was using normal JAVA request/response mothod through BufferReader, but it's ugly way and i want to change it.

Comment: A few code snippets, such as cxf endpoint config or how you're actually launching the app and exposing your service, might provide valuable information making it easier to decipher the issue